# Apache Tomcat will not start on Mac

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, server

I cannot get Apache Tomcat to start.  I followed the instructions for installing Tomcat on the Mac found at https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-install-tomcat-in-macos/.

After I type the command to start Tomcat, the response from the command line is that `Tomcat has started`.

However, when I go to the browser, the default page is not showing up. I further checked to see if the port was being used by using the command

```
lsof -nP -i4TCP:8080 | grep LISTEN
```

which showed that no program is using the port.  I also read the 'RUNNING.txt' that instructed me on setting the environmental variables, which I did.  Any suggestions on why Tomcat is not starting up.

I'm using `jdk 1.8.0_202` and `Apache Tomcat 9.0.14` that is running of  Mac OS High Sierra.

Comment: Have you checked Tomcat logs?

Comment: Ivan, I just checked the logs.  The file in the log directory, catalina.out, is zero bytes.  Each time I try to start Tomcat, the only thing that changes regarding the file is the 'Date Modified' field.

Answer (score 1):

## BatChmod

[image: Logo and tag line for the BatChmod app]

After downloading a fresh version of Tomcat, I use the [*BatChmod*](http://www.lagentesoft.com/batchmod/index.html) app to alter the [file permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions). **Tomcat will not launch properly** without altering the permissions.

I do not know the [command-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) equivalent, but here is a screenshot of the settings I have used for years successfully.

[image: screenshot of BatChmod.app settings for Apache Tomcat file permissions]

## Plea for help

If anyone can write the equivalent as a [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) for [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS), please post!

Even better, explain how to wrap such a script as an [AppleScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) for [drag-and-drop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_and_drop) execution in [Finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software)).

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a permissions problem.  When I installed Tomcat, I put the folder in the '/Library/Tomcat' directory.  Even though the Tomcat files were changed to be executable, the user and group ownership remained the same.  To get Tomcat to run, I moved the directory to 'Users/MyUserName/Tomcat'.  Once I did that, the default Tomcat page ran.